# i cant display posts' category with manyToMany relationship

Tags: php, laravel, pivot

i cant display posts' category with manyToMany relationship. i build relationship but can't display it.

// here is my post model

```
public function getCategory(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class,
'post_categories','id','post_id');
   }
```

// here is my controller

```
public function Allindex(){
    $posts=Post::all();

    return view('allposts',compact('posts'));

}
```

//here is my allposts blade

```
   <div class="media-body">
<a href="/users" class="anchor-username"><h4 class="media-heading">{{$post->pivot['name']}}</h4></a>
<a href="/posts" class="anchor-time">{{$post->created_at}}</a>
   </div>
```

Comment: where are you calling the relationship?

Comment: try `@foreach($post->getCategory as $category) {{ $category->name }} @endforeach`

Answer (score 1):

You are passing the wrong param in a model relationship.

```
public function getCategory(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class,'post_categories','post_id','category_id');
}
```

Now you can access it as below.

```
@foreach($post->getCategory as $category) 
{{ $category->name }} 
@endforeach
```

Or

```
{{ $post->getCategory->pluck('name')->implode(',') }}
```

Comment: Note that this will run a separate database query for each post.

Answer (score -1):

Laravel is not automatically loading your relationship, the keyword you are looking for is [eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading).

You can eager load relationships with the `with` method like so:

```
$posts = Post::with('getCategory')->get();
```